# Why is the Display(Name = "") attribute ignored in one of my ViewModels while it seems to work in my other models in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, attributes

I have a viewmodel BeerNamePartialVM which has a property with a [Display(Name = "")] attribute that doesn't seem to work. I've also included my base model which also has a property with a [Display(Name = "")] attribute, which does work:

```
public class BeerNamePartialViewModel : IPartialPropertySearch
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Name or partial name")]
    //[DisplayName("Name or partial name")]
    public string PartialName { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class BierProperties
{
    [Required, StringLength(50), Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The two highlighted texts are generated with DisplayNameFor HtmlHelper functions shown below:

```
@model MVCBierApplication.Interfaces.IPartialPropertySearch
@Html.DisplayNameFor(f => f.PartialName)
@Html.EditorFor(f => f.PartialName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(f => f.PartialName)
...

@{Beer emptyModel = new Bier();}
@if (Model.Results != null && Model.Results.Count() != 0)
{
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(h => Model.emptyModel.Naam</td>
            ...
        </tr>
        ...
```

the emptyModel is an empty model of type Beer, which I use to build the table header. This was neccecary because my view has the interface `IPartialPropertySearch` as its model, which returns the results in an IEnumerable of type Object instead of Beer. This was done because I want to reuse my code for models other than Beer.

The result looks like this (this is my first question so I didn't have enough reputation to display the images in-post):

[image: printscreen of my result]

Notice the highlighted labels. The label above the textbox seems to ignore it's property's [Display] attribute, while the label in the table header works as expected.

I've also tried to use the [DisplayName("name")], first on its own and then even together with [Display(Name =)] but neither seem to work. I've restarted my IIS server, cleared my browser's cache and ran the app in four different browsers, all of which give the same result.

The [Required] attribute does work, when I submit the form without entering a name, the errormessage set in the [required] tag gets shown. The only properties that are getting ignored are those that alter the name:

[image: printscheen with errormessage]

I've also included a [link](https://github.com/Spifffff/MVCBierApplication) to the project's repository in case my images weren't clear enough or if you want to test this yourself. Some parts might be in Dutch but I think it should be clear enough. There's also an SQL file included in the repository to recreate the database I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because your model is referencing the interface and not the class.  `@model MVCBierApplication.Interfaces.IPartialPropertySearch` change it to `@model MVCBierApplication.Models.BeerNamePartialViewModel`

Comment: That solved it. I ended up adding the Annotation to the interface instead of changing the model, both ended up working so I chose the way that still enabled me to use the same viewmodel for multiple models. Thank you for the quick response.